# Regex to get words or series of words that start with a capital letter

Tags: regex

I want to get all words that start with a capital letter, but also groups of consecutive words that each start with capital letters.

For example in the sentence,

> Obama told reporters in Washington that he and Netanyahu are opposed
>   to Iran's calls for "Death To America"

I want to get

```
[Obama, Washington, Netanyahu, Iran's, Death To America]
```

I've tried

```regex
([A-Z][a-z]*\s)+
```

meaning a `capital letter followed by any number of small letters followed by a space, any amount of times.

I though this would work but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: why `Death to America` satisfies your criterion?

Comment: are your using pcre?

Comment: Explain this > but also groups of consecutive words that each start with capital letters.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Iran's` does not match `[A-Z][a-z]`; add `'` in your set.

`Death To America` does not match entirely because the last word is not followed by a space.

Both fixed by

```
([A-Z][a-z']*)(\s[A-Z][a-z']*)*
```

You don't have words that do not start with a capital but have one in between; if you want to ignore these, use Word Breaks:

```
\b([A-Z][a-z']*)(\s[A-Z][a-z']*)*\b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your regular expression using an optional group that repeats "zero or more" times.

```
[A-Z][a-z']+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xI7dZ6/1)

Comment: If you want it to match a single capital letter, just change the first `+` to `*` ...

Answer (score 0):

assume you prefer longest match, then

```
([A-Z][\w']*(?:\s+[A-Z][\w']*)*)
```

apply with `g`, should get all groupings.

```
[A-Z][\w']*
```

matches individual word you would like to match.

then

```
(?:\s+[A-Z][\w']*)*
```

will match arbitrary number of sequence of this kind of words.